# Using AspectJ get context of running class

Tags: android, aspectj

I am using AspectJ for monitoring an Android app. My AspectJ code is something like this -

```
public  aspect Tester {

 pointcut methodCalls():
          execution(* com.example.buttontestaspect..*(..))&& !within(com.example.buttontestaspect.Tester);

 before(): methodCalls(){
String n =  thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature().toString();
//Gives the package and class 
// Here I also want to get the context of that class
}

}
```

In the above code, when String 'n' is executed, I also want to get the context of the class. How do I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by the context of the class? Signature provides the getDeclaringType()-method to get the class in which it is defined. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: No I actually need the context like in Android you have this.context = context for an activity; Similarly when a particular class is being executed, I want to retrieve its context from my Aspect. I dont know how to retrieve it...

Comment: So in essence you want to access a field of the instance?

Comment: Have a look at *target* then: https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/language-joinPoints.html That can inject the instance into the aspect's execution.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is wat i was looking for :)